# Randym/axlsx - gem, Styling Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, axlsx

I have been using rails randym/axlsx gem, version 2.0.1, for generating excel view in my application. I have certain issues related to the styling of the excel sheet.

*This is the **html file** am trying to implement in excel.*
[image]

So far i have been successful in displaying all the contents correctly towards all the four sides. But am  stuck at the Cross section in the middle.

This is the sample of **excel file** i have generated as if now:
[image]

To bring the diagonals, as mentioned in the randym/axlsx document, I tried,

```
style.add_style( border: { style: :thin, color: "000000", :edges => [:left, :right, :top, :bottom, :diagonal]   } )
```

But except the diagonal edges in *":edges => [:left, :right, :top, :bottom, :diagonal]"*, all other edges where displayed correctly in the excel sheet.

***1. Why is the diagonal edges not working?

 2. How to align all the four texts in each portion of the diagonal as in the above image?***

Another problem i am facing is that, I brought an image to the excel file using the below code:

```
sheet.add_image(:image_src => img) do |image|
    image.width = 20
    image.height = 20
    image.start_at column, row
end
```

The image is positioned at the top left corner of the cell.

***3. How do i position the image at the center of the cell?***

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may be help you-

```
style.add_style( border: { style: :thin, color: "000000", :alignment=>{:horizontal => :center}  } )
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you meant by border alignment, this code didn't work for me as well.